# Finding the critical $P,T$ and $V$ in VDW / Berthelot equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, gas

I need to find the critical pressure, temperature, and volume from the Berthelot equation: $$\left(P+\frac{a}{vT}\right)(v-b)=RT$$ in terms of the parameters: $a,b,R$ . The problem is pretty similar to the problem of finding the critical point in VDW gas, and I found this derivation in some textbooks.

I can see how the conditions on the derivatives: $$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_{t=t_c}=0$$ $$\left(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial V^2}\right)_{t=t_c}=0$$
define the critical point.

I have yet failed to understand the condition on the critical volume, which is: $$(v-v_c)^3=0$$ This condition is the one eventually used for finding the critical point in the textbooks I was looking at. This is done by rewriting VDW\Berthelot equation $$v^3-\left(b+\frac{RT}{P}\right)v^2+\frac{a}{TP}-\frac{ab}{TP}=0$$  and  equating the coefficients of similar powers of $v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Zemansky: Heat and Thermodynamics, p135, Berthelot's equation is 
$$(p+\frac{a}{v^2T})(v-b)=RT \tag{1}\label{1} $$
which we can rearrange as $p=\frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2T}$. Now take 1st and 2nd partial derivatives with respect to $v$ and equate them to zero:
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial v} = -\frac{RT}{(v-b)^2} + \frac{2a}{v^3T}=0\\
\frac{\partial ^2 p}{\partial v^2} = \frac{2RT}{(v-b)^3} - \frac{6a}{v^4T}=0$$

Rewrite them as

$$ RT_c^2 v_c^3 = 2a(v_c-b)^2 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$RT_c^2v_c^4 = 3a (v_c-b)^3 \tag{3}\label{3} $$

Divide $\eqref{3}$ by $\eqref{2}$ This is solved by $v_c=3b$ and $T_c=\sqrt { \frac{8a}{27Rb}}$

Comment: Thank you very much!
I think there is a factor of $b$ missing in the term of $T_c$ : $$T_c=\sqrt{\frac{8a}{27bR}}$$

Comment: you are right, just fixed it, thank you